# Inputs are losing their values when parent is filtered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Basically, I have a directive (call it a site, i.e. location) which has many inputs for collecting data. There can be hundreds of them on the page, so I have a search input for quickly finding a specific site.

My problem is that whenever the search is used, the items that are filtered out lose all the data that was entered for them. I expected the filtered items to "hide" and maintain their values, but it seems like they're being re-rendered instead. Am I doing something wrong, or how can I accomplish this the correct way?

[Here's a very simple Plunker of my issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysTZaLNbm9HnKAx3PHFi?p=preview)

The HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter sites...">
  <my-directive ng-repeat="site in sites | filter:q" site="site"></my-directive>
</body>
```

The script:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sites = [
    {name: 'site 1', id:'site1'},
    {name: 'site 2', id:'site2'}
    ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      site: '=',
    },
    template: '<h1>{{site.name}}</h1>Value: <input name="{{site.id}}">'
  };
});
```

Comment: You're refreshing the ng-repeat every time you do a search and thus recreating the directives without any data in the input.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing binding your input values to the model. When angular redraws the UI it creates new elements, so anything typed previously is not stored without using `ng-model` (or events) to store the values

Try this:

```
template: '<h1>{{site.name}}</h1>Value: <input name="{{site.id}}" ng-model="site.SomeProperty">'
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5pFzueCBf1h77TTB9kfC?p=preview)